# Laravel validation fails returning random data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I've written an API where I'm using the FormRequests in some methods. 
When the validation on the FormRequest fails, it does return random data.

I really don't know where to look, I've tried many things but I couldn't fix it.
Here I've listed the things I tried to fix the issue:

- Changed the FormRequest to a normal Request and use `$this->validate()`. Still returning the random data.
- Tried a `dd()` in the `formatErrors()` method, but didn't reach it.
- Tried a `dd()` in the constructor of the abstract `Request` class, this did display the dump.
- Didn't use validation, but just the Request class and this did work. The random data didn't show up (but I really need to validate the Request though).

It seem like when I want to use the Validation functionality inside Laravel, I get this random data returned. When I just use the Request object, the code just runs, but I get errors cause of the data that isn't present.

**The method looks like:**

```
public function upload(ScheduleRequest $request, Uploader $uploader)
{
  dd('Wut');
}
```

**The FormRequest looks like:**

```
class ScheduleRequest extends Request {

   public function rules()
   {
      return [
        'file' => 'required',
        'team_id' => 'required|exists:teams,id',
        'week' => 'required|numeric'
      ];
   }
}
```

**Edit: so I've figured out that on the validation fail it's going to another controller method for no reason..**

*TLDR; When validation fails, I get data returned that isn't suppose to return. Instead of displaying the dump: `Wut`.*

Somebody has this issue as well or knows where to look to fix this?
**I'm using Laravel 5.**

Comment: Can we see some code? Also, what does the random data look like?

Comment: I've edited the question. The random data is returning data of the current user. Which I've not writting in the controller or something. This shouldn't be displayed at all. I dont have a clue where it reaching that endpoint.

Comment: On the laravel validation documentation, it says "If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors." So it doesn't look like it should get to your dump.

Comment: You know what, I finally got it............... Somehow Postman did delete the 'X-Requested-With' header so Laravel didn't see the request as an HTTP call............ I love this job......... </3